# Scheme/Racket filter/map multiple arguments

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, map-function

Lets say I want to do the following:

```
(define (foo lst x)
   (filter function lst)
```

but `function` takes in 2 arguments (and `function` was given to me), one being the list `lst` it will use, and the other being `x`. Syntactically, how would I change that line to pass in the second argument? Sorry I am new to Scheme/DrRacket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, using [`curry`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffunction..rkt%29._curry%29%29):

```
(define (foo lst x)
   (filter (curry function x) lst))
```

That is, assuming that `function` takes as first parameter `x` and as second parameter each one of the elements in `lst`. In other words, the above is equivalent to this:

```
(define (foo lst x)
  (filter (lambda (e) (function x e))
          lst))
```

Either way: the trick (called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)) is to create a new function that receives a single argument, and passes it to the original function, which has the other argument fixed with the given `x` value.

In your question, it's not clear in which order we should pass the arguments, but once you understand the basic principle at work here, you'll be able to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is:

```
(define (foo ys x)
   (filter (λ (y) (function y x)) ys)
```

An alternative:

```
(define (foo ys x)
   (for/list                    ; collect results into a list
      ([y ys]]                  ; for each element y in the list ys
        #:when (function y x))  ;   when (function y x) collect
      x))                             x
```

Or without comments:

```
 (define (foo ys x)
   (for/list ([y ys]] #:when (function y x))
      x)))
```